# Merge two arrays of objects with separate ids, so that the objects don't duplicate

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects, each object has .id property. I need to merge them so that in the return array, each object id is unique (object whos .id is already   present in other object in that array, when trying to join the array is discarded). Preferably es6 way. Thanks!

```
 var a = [{id: 2}, {id:3}]

 var b = [{id: 4}, { id:3}]

 mergeArrays(a,b)
  // should return 
  ////[{id: 2}, {id:3}, {id: 4}]`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide input/output examples and your attempt at solving the problem to get assistance. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're unsure of what makes a question answerable.

Comment: Create an object whose keys are the IDs. Then add each object to this object, that will filter out duplicate IDs. Finally, get the elements of the object back into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach: concatenate the two arrays into one and reduce them into an object by id which removes duplicates. Grabbing an array of values with `Object.values()` produces the desired result:

```js
var a = [{id: 2}, {id:3}]
var b = [{id: 4}, {id:3}]

const result = Object.values(a.concat(b).reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.id] = e;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Note that `b`'s keys will overwrite any duplicate keys from `a` because of the order of the concatenation.